# How to select a command from specific package

Tags: command-line, package-management, mysql

I am having two packages having the same command. How do I specify the command to execute by a selected package.

```
harsha20599@harsha20599-Inspro:~$ mysql
The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.7
 * mariadb-client-core-10.1
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

I am a noobie in linux and thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

It appears mysql is not installed in your system. As the command output suggests:

```
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7
```

If you want to install mysql server, see the following link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/.../how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04